# Tabs in Accordion not styling properly

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

So when there's only 1 accordion dd (item with content, for lack of better term) and I code it to be active when the page loads, everything functions as expected and active tab-title is properly highlighted.

But when there's more than 1 accordion dd and they're loaded unactive, then clicked on, the active tab-title doesn't highlight until clicked on AGAIN.

Here's the solution I think I need: in foundation.css, when an accordion content is active, I want to make the first tab tab-title and content active.  Thoughts?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 small-centered columns">
      <dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
         <dd id="MEALROW_55" class='active'>
           <a href="#meal_55">Sweet and Sour Chicken   &nbsp;&nbsp; <span class='secondary round label'>Shared</span> <span class="tag-right">&nbsp; Tags: Asian, Chicken</span></a>
             <div id="meal_55" class="content active">

         <div class="row"><div class="small-12 large-4 columns" style="font-size:80%;">
            <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
               <dd class="tab-title active"><a href="#i_55" style="font-size:85%;">Ingredients</a></dd>
               <dd class="tab-title"><a href="#s_55" style="font-size:85%;">Shopping List</a></dd>
            </dl>

            <div class="tabs-content">
            <div class="content active" id="i_55">
            3-5 chicken breast<br>salt and pepper<br>1 cup cornstarch<br>2 eggs, beaten<br>1/3 cup canola oil<br>3/4 cups white sugar<br>4 Tablespoons ketchup<br>1/2 cup white distilled vinegar<br>1 Tablespoon soy sauce<br>1 teaspoon garlic salt<br>
            </div>
            <div class="content" id="s_55">
            3-5 chicken breast<br>salt and pepper<br>1 cup cornstarch<br>2 eggs, beaten<br>1/3 cup canola oil<br>3/4 cups white sugar<br>4 Tablespoons ketchup<br>1/2 cup white distilled vinegar<br>1 Tablespoon soy sauce<br>1 teaspoon garlic salt<br>
            </div>
            </div>
         </div>

               </div>
         </dd>
       </dl>
          </div>
    </div>
```